# WPF AxisAngleRotation3D vs. XNA CreateFromAxisAngle

Tags: c#, wpf, xna

I am pretty dumb to 3D, just like my question may be:

I made a "viewer" program in WPF that renders stuff on screen, and what may be rotated as well. I use this for rotation what works for my taste:

Code: WPF

```
Transform3DGroup tg = new Transform3DGroup();
tg.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform3D(sx, sy, 1));
tg.Children.Add(new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), rx)));
tg.Children.Add(new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), ry)));
tg.Children.Add(new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), rz)));
tg.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform3D(x, y, z));
darabka.Transform = tg;
TeljesModell.Children.Add(darabka);
```

I decided to make this program in XNA, because that seems to be a bit faster, however I could not make it to work.

Tried this way (Code, XNA):

```
Pozició = Matrix.CreateScale(sx, sy, 1f);                          //méretezés
Pozició *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitX, rx);          //forgatás
Pozició *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitY, ry);
Pozició *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitZ, rz);
Pozició *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(x, y, z);                      //középpont
```

I tried even CreateFromYawPitchRoll, CreateRotationX(YZ) too, but without luck, the stuff drawed on screen was always differently rotated. So I guessed I ask the brains here if they know **what math I am to put into between the two technologies**.

Thanks in advance.

**edit**: I tried on other forums where I was asked for details. I copy / paste them here too
The XNA code is like:

main

```
...
protected override void LoadContent()
{
t3 = new Airplane(); //this is a "zone" object, having zone regions and zone objects in it. all of them together give the zone itself as a static object, where player walks in
Kamera.Példány.Pozició = new Vector3(1362, 627, -757); //starting pozition in the zone - this is camera position so the player's starting pozition. (camera is FPS)
...
}
...
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
...
Kameramozgatása();                                                              //kamera mozgatását vezérlő billentyűk
//this moves the FPS camera around
}
...
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
...
ÁltalánosGrafikaiObjektumok.Effect.View = Kamera.Példány.Idenézünk;                 //camera views this
ÁltalánosGrafikaiObjektumok.Effect.Projection = projectionMatrix;                   //... and camera views FROM is set in Kameramozgatása()
...
t3.Rajzolj();  //draw zone object
...
}
```

zone object

```
constructor: set the effect and device to the same as main, set the Pozició (a matrix containing the current position and rotations) to origo
...
public virtual Alapmodel Inicializálás(float x, float y, float z, float rx, float ry, float rz, float sx, float sy)
{
//this initializer starts when the coordinates are from a file and not set with Pozició = Matrix....., so we are to convert. this runs only one time. overrides set the vertex positions and textures
VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(device, VertexPositionTexture.VertexElements);
Pozició = Matrix.CreateScale(sx, sy, 1f);             //méretezés
Pozició *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitX, rx);     //forgatás
Pozició *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitY, ry);
Pozició *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitZ, rz);
Pozició *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(x, y, z);           //középpont
//we set the starting position - nowhere else we do it, from here only the main loop can modify this,... could.. but does not. this is zone, and has only static objects - never moving
}
public void Rajzolj()
{
//this draws the object (what can be a zone or a static object in it)
foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
  pass.Begin();
  foreach (Elem elem in Elemek)
  {
    //végigmegyünk az elemeken        
    effect.Texture = elem.Textúra;

    //pozicionálás
    effect.World = Pozició;  //we take the initialized position

    effect.CommitChanges(); //this is needed. if you do not use this, the textures will be screwed up
    device.VertexDeclaration = VertexDeclaration;
    device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, Poziciók, 0, Poziciók.Length, elem.Indexek, 0, elem.Indexek.Length / 3);
    }
  pass.End();
  }
}
```

That's it. I still guess it is some conversion and not the drawing code. Nowhere else is the position altered. I guessed that matrices are just like WPFs stacked transforms - my problem was and is that I do not know the math to convert between the two. The WPF code works perfectly, the models in the zone show up good. **The XNA code is bad somehow, because the Inicializálás() has wrong conversion from x,y,z,etc. in it. In this I do need help.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: forgot to add: XNA 3.1 - but I guess in this case it is not a biggy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CreateWorld too, but that has no scaling in it, so I decided to solve this step-by-step. First is putting to origo, then scaling, then rotating the scaled, then pozitioning the scaled and rotated.

You are to use radian, instead of degree, if you have degree, use the MathHelper.ToRadians(), like I did.

If you come from WPF and your rotation angles are working there, but here not, try to multiply your angle with 360/512 before you calc it to radians. You see example for this in comment, you are to use it to all rx,ry and rz.

```
        Pozició = Matrix.CreateTranslation(Vector3.Zero);                     //alappozíció az origó
        if (sx != 1 || sy != 1) Pozició *= Matrix.CreateScale(sx, sy, 1f);    //méretezés
        if (rx != 0 || ry != 0 || rz != 0) Pozició *= Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(
                              MathHelper.ToRadians(rx)                        //WPFből: MathHelper.ToRadians(rx * 360f / 512f)
                              , MathHelper.ToRadians(ry)
                              , MathHelper.ToRadians(rz)
                              );
        if (x != 0 || y != 0 || z != 0) Pozició *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(x, y, z);                         //középpont
```

If you can give faster formula then *360/512, or something that looks better, please comment.

Answer (score 1):

I advise against storing your orientation in an angular fashion that way...

But there are times when your issue can be solved in the xna version simply by applying the Z rotation first, Then X, then Y.

Comment: Tried, but did not work for me. I do not think it is the order of rotations, because when I try CreateFromYawPitchRoll that is all rotations at once, and that did not work too. This is why I guess it is some math, some conversion perhaps between the input in XNA and input in WPF.

Comment: I would like to convince you that your problem/solution would be simplified hugely if you mind shift away from rx, ry, and rz, and store the orientation in a matrix or quaternion instead. but I don't thing the character limit in this comment section will allow it and it isn't a direct answer to your question so I won't. If you end up staying stuck, consider alternate orientation representations.

Comment: The "pozició" in the XNA code sample is Matrix type, I just am to convert the coordinates and rotations (and scaling) from other source (from a file).